Como agregar datos a un archivo .txt con Python?
Como puedo agregar datos a un archivo .txt con Python sin borrar o cambiar el que ya existe?
Este es mi código:


with open("Practica.txt", "w") as datos:
    archivo = datos.write("Hola1")



Cada vez que lo ejecuto me cambia los datos que tenia antes y solo almecena el texto Hola1

Usando el modo "a" (append) en lugar de "w", with open("Practica.txt", "a") as datos: Mínimo es leer la documentación.

Simplemente cambia el modo en open(), indica a (abrir para escribir, añadiendo al final del archivo si existe) en lugar de w (abrir para escribir, truncando primero el archivo):
Ejemplo:
with open("Practica.txt", "a") as datos:
    archivo = datos.write("Hola1")


Podrías editar el enlace para incluir la documentación en español añadiendo /es/ entre python.org y dev.

@JorgeLuis, es verdad! Gracias por la observación.
